# Can not add accounts-password, how to fix this?

Tags: meteor

I am trying to add accounts-password package to my project, but I get this error instead, I have no clue what causes it or how to fix it. I tried to run

`meteor npm install node-gyp` rebuild as mentioned in the error but it does not help...

> ```
>     ...seed>meteor add accounts-password
>  => Errors while adding packages:
>
> While loading package npm-bcrypt@0.8.7:
> error: Command failed:
> C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.0-1\mt-os.windows.x86_
> 32\dev_bundle\bin\npm.cmd
> rebuild --no-bin-links --update-binary
> gyp ERR! build error
> gyp ERR! stack Error:
> `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe` failed with exit
> code: 1
> gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit
> (C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.0-1\mt-os.windows.x86
> _32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:276:23)
> gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
> gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
> gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit
> (internal/child_process.js:200:12)
> gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
> gyp ERR! command
> "C:\\Users\\...\\AppData\\Local\\.meteor\\packages\\meteor-tool\\1.4.0-1\\mt-os.wi
> ndows.x86_32\\dev_bundle\\bin\\node.exe"
> "C:\\Users\\...\\AppData\\Local\\.meteor\\packages\\meteor-tool\\1.4.0-1\\mt-os.wi
> ndows.x86_32\\dev_bundle\\lib\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js"
> "rebuild"
> gyp ERR! cwd
> C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\npm-bcrypt\0.8.7\npm\node_modules\.tem
> p-pilafw\node_modules\bcrypt
> gyp ERR! node -v v4.4.7
> gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.4.0
> gyp ERR! not ok
>
> npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
> npm ERR! argv
> "C:\\Users\\...\\AppData\\Local\\.meteor\\packages\\meteor-tool\\1.4.0-1\\mt-os.wi
> ndows.x86_32\\dev_bundle\\bin\\node.exe"
> "C:\\Users\\...\\AppData\\Local\\.meteor\\packages\\meteor-tool\\1.4.0-1\\mt-os.wi
> ndows.x86_32\\dev_bundle\\lib\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js"
> "rebuild" "--no-bin-links" "--update-binary"
> npm ERR! node v4.4.7
> npm ERR! npm  v3.10.5
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
> npm ERR! bcrypt@0.8.7 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
> npm ERR! Exit status 1
> npm ERR!
> npm ERR! Failed at the bcrypt@0.8.7 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'.
> npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
> npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the bcrypt package,
> npm ERR! not with npm itself.
> npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
> npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
> npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project
> with:
> npm ERR!     npm bugs bcrypt
> npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
> npm ERR!     npm owner ls bcrypt
> npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
> npm ERR!
> C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\npm-bcrypt\0.8.7\npm\node_modules\.tem
> p-pilafw\npm-debug.log
> gyp ERR! build error
> gyp ERR! stack Error:
> `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe` failed with exit
> code: 1
> gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit
> (C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.0-1\mt-os.windows.x86
> _32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:276:23)
> gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
> gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
> gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit
> (internal/child_process.js:200:12)
> gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
> gyp ERR! command
> "C:\\Users\\...\\AppData\\Local\\.meteor\\packages\\meteor-tool\\1.4.0-1\\mt-os.wi
> ndows.x86_32\\dev_bundle\\bin\\node.exe"
> "C:\\Users\\...\\AppData\\Local\\.meteor\\packages\\meteor-tool\\1.4.0-1\\mt-os.wi
> ndows.x86_32\\dev_bundle\\lib\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js"
> "rebuild"
> gyp ERR! cwd
> C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\npm-bcrypt\0.8.7\npm\node_modules\.tem
> p-pilafw\node_modules\bcrypt
> gyp ERR! node -v v4.4.7
> gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.4.0
> gyp ERR! not ok
>
> npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
> npm ERR! argv
> "C:\\Users\\...\\AppData\\Local\\.meteor\\packages\\meteor-tool\\1.4.0-1\\mt-os.wi
> ndows.x86_32\\dev_bundle\\bin\\node.exe"
> "C:\\Users\\...\\AppData\\Local\\.meteor\\packages\\meteor-tool\\1.4.0-1\\mt-os.wi
> ndows.x86_32\\dev_bundle\\lib\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js"
> "rebuild" "--no-bin-links" "--update-binary"
> npm ERR! node v4.4.7
> npm ERR! npm  v3.10.5
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
> npm ERR! bcrypt@0.8.7 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
> npm ERR! Exit status 1
> npm ERR!
> npm ERR! Failed at the bcrypt@0.8.7 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'.
> npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
> npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the bcrypt package,
> npm ERR! not with npm itself.
> npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
> npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
> npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project
> with:
> npm ERR!     npm bugs bcrypt
> npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
> npm ERR!     npm owner ls bcrypt
> npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
> npm ERR!
> C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\npm-bcrypt\0.8.7\npm\node_modules\.tem
> p-pilafw\npm-debug.log
> ```

Im am using Windows7-x64. meteor 1.4.0.1 and the inspina meteor theme.

I reinstalled meteor, I tried to create a new virgin project and add accounts-password to it, but I get the same issue...

Tried to install meteor on my Laptop, and getting the same issue... is there something wrong with meteor itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your issue is mentioned [here](https://github.com/ncb000gt/node.bcrypt.js/issues/98).

Try to run `npm install --global --production windows-build-tools` from Powershell as mentioned [here](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#installation)

Comment: For newbies like me out there: go to start type in the search bar: Windows PowerShell, right-click on it and open as administrator. The PowerShell opens. Type in 'meteor npm install --global --production windows-build-tools' and then wait, wait, and wait some longer. After everything is installed, there was no confirmation. But somehow that fixed the issue, and now I can add the accounts-password package. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If some one who tired of trying 'npm install --global --production windows-build-tools', they can skip it after the Python installation and continue buid tools manually, by browsing to C:\Users\#user#\.windows-build-tools'. Refer this [link](https://forums.meteor.com/t/how-to-fix-the-bcrypt-error-in-windows-7/28856/25?u=samahudin)